# local jmx connection using visual Vm

Tags: visualvm

According to oracle documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/jmx_connections.html
The target application should be run on same host as Java VisualVM but was started by a different user than the one who started Java VisualVM.But,in my case i am making log in as suppose X user.And i am starting both VisualVM and target application.How it is possible to run VisualVM by one user and target application by another user on the same localhost?

Comment: please accept best answer

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right page. You need to create an explicit JMX connection as the page describes:

> **When Are Explicit JMX Connections Necessary?**
>
> - The target application is running on the same host as Java VisualVM but was started by a different user than the one who started Java VisualVM. Java VisualVM discovers running applications using the jps tool, which can only discover Java applications started by  the same user as the one who starts the Java VisualVM tool.